# Clear understanding of java equals method

Tags: java, hashmap, equals, hashcode

What happens if my equals method (overridden in employee class - which is acting as key) always returns true (hardcoded) or always returns false?

Also similary, can I user Math.random as hashcode? Why or why cant i do that?

Comment: Is this java? If so, please add a java tag.

Comment: Minor corrections.

Comment: yea - this is for java. thanks for letting me know. i will ensure to take care of this in my future questions.